# C# set KeyValue to variables in one line

Tags: c#, linq, syntactic-sugar

Is there any short version of first 3 lines of code:

```
foreach (var el in craftSystem.requiredItems)
        {
            var type = el.Key;
            var count = el.Value;
            var itemDefinition = ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(type);

            var go = Instantiate(prefab, root);

            var line = go.GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();
            line.SetItem(itemDefinition, count);
        }
```

to set suitables variable names, like type, count in example above.

I understand that code looks fine and readable and it can be simpler, because I use variable only once. But I was need to know how to put it in one line (see the answer).

Comment: use `List`for that

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you mean the three lines inside the loop?

Comment: You seem to use those "helper" variables only once, so why not just `var itemDefinition = ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(el.Key);` and `line.SetItem(itemDefinition, el.Value);`? -- and maybe even `var line = Instantiate(prefab, root).GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();` --- if you *really* want to "save lines"... but as it is now. it looks pretty readable, so why change it at all? -- It **is** more readable now **because** it's several lines.

Comment: Yes there is, but LINQ won't do that for you. LINQ can only select data from your input, it won't change the input. Use `List.Foreach` to change your input sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks simple enough, but only for sake of your question you can deconstruct key-value pairs

```
foreach ((var type, count) in requiredItems.Select(pair => (pair.Key, pair.Value)))
{
    var itemDefinition = ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(type);

    var go = Instantiate(prefab, root);

    var line = go.GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();
    line.SetItem(itemDefinition, count);
}
```

Comment: thx! can use one var `foreach (var (type, count) in craftSystem.requiredItems.Select(pair => (pair.Key, pair.Value)))`

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
var go = Instantiate(prefab, root);
var line = go.GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();
line.SetItem(ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(el.Key), el.Value);
```

but it would be harder to debug (see comment above from @Corak)

Comment: yes, that's easy way, but no sense under el.Key and el.Value

Answer (score 1):

Or you can reformat like:

```
craftSystem.requiredItems.ToList().ForEach(el => 
                       {
                            var itemDefinition = ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(el.Key);
                            var go = Instantiate(prefab, root);
                            var line = go.GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();
                            line.SetItem(itemDefinition, el.Value);
                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Improve this issue like:

```
dataList.requiredData.ToList().ForEach(x => 
                   {
                        var item = ItemManager.GetItemDefinition(x.Key);
                        var instance = Instantiate(prefab, root);
                        var line = go.GetComponent<UICraftItemRequirementLine>();
                        line.SetItem(itemDefinition, x.Value);
                   });
```

In C# we have extension method like `ForEach()` that works as foreach(), but with lambda expression.

GoodLuck.